# Struggling to create an efficient index for this MYSQL query with JOIN and grou

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7

I'm running a MySQL query on a dataset that currently has approx 26M rows and is growing by 5-10M rows per year.

This is the primary table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ledger_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ledger_entry_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_pms_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remaining_amount_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remaining_amount_currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `external_ledger_entry_type_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_provider_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_patient_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_account_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_guarantor_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_claim_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance_currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'USD',
  `surface_mesial` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_distal` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_occlusal` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_lingual` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_facial` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surface_class_5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tooth_range_start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tooth_range_end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_ins_paid_amount_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondary_ins_paid_amount_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ignore_for_payroll` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `external_updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ar_remaining_amount_cents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ar_remaining_amount_currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_type_and_id` (`type`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_local_pms_id_and_external_id` (`local_pms_id`,`external_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_patient_id` (`patient_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_provider_id` (`provider_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_ledger_entry_type_id` (`ledger_entry_type_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_local_pms_id` (`local_pms_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_check_number` (`check_number`),
  KEY `date_loc_prov_type` (`date`,`location_id`,`provider_id`,`type`),
  KEY `index_le_on_external_let_id` (`external_ledger_entry_type_id`),
  KEY `index_le_on_external_provider_id` (`external_provider_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_type` (`type`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_date_and_location_id` (`date`,`location_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_date` (`date`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_type_and_location_id_and_date` (`type`,`location_id`,`date`),
  KEY `temp_location_id_let_id_date` (`location_id`,`ledger_entry_type_id`,`date`),
  KEY `index_le_on_location_let_date` (`location_id`,`ledger_entry_type_id`,`date`),
  KEY `index_le_on_external_account_id` (`external_account_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_external_id` (`external_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_date_and_type` (`date`,`type`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_provider_id_and_date_and_type` (`provider_id`,`date`,`type`),
  KEY `index_le_date_location_type_amount_cents` (`date`,`location_id`,`type`,`amount_cents`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `le_date_loc_type_prov_cent` (`date`,`location_id`,`type`,`provider_id`,`amount_cents`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_ledger_entry_type_id_and_date` (`ledger_entry_type_id`,`date`),
  KEY `le_date_type_loc_pro_cen_pat` (`date`,`type`,`location_id`,`provider_id`,`amount_cents`,`patient_id`),
  KEY `le_external_ids` (`id`,`external_id`,`local_pms_id`),
  KEY `le_balance_by_acct` (`balance_cents`,`account_id`),
  KEY `index_ledger_entries_on_account_id_and_amount_cents` (`account_id`,`amount_cents`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_29eb3a7e59` FOREIGN KEY (`ledger_entry_type_id`) REFERENCES `ledger_entry_types` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_95dd992850` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_95dd992851` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patients` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55586430 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the query I need to optimize is:

```
SELECT ledger_entries.date, locations.acct_codename, ledger_entries.provider_id, providers.name, ledger_entry_types.shortcode, ledger_entry_types.title, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT ledger_entries.patient_id) as 'patient count', SUM(amount_cents)/100 as 'Total Amount' FROM ledger_entries
LEFT JOIN locations ON ledger_entries.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN providers ON ledger_entries.provider_id = providers.id
LEFT JOIN ledger_entry_types ON ledger_entries.ledger_entry_type_id = ledger_entry_types.id
WHERE (ledger_entries.type IS NULL OR ledger_entries.type IN ('Procedure', 'Adjustment', 'AncillarySale'))
AND ledger_entries.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-30'
AND locations.active = true
GROUP BY ledger_entries.date, ledger_entries.provider_id, ledger_entries.location_id, ledger_entries.ledger_entry_type_id;
```

And here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "ledger_entries",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "index_ledger_entries_on_type_and_id,date_loc_prov_type,index_ledger_entries_on_type,index_ledger_entries_on_date_and_location_id,index_ledger_entries_on_date,index_ledger_entries_on_type_and_location_id_and_date,index_ledger_entries_on_date_and_type,index_le_date_location_type_amount_cents,le_date_loc_type_prov_cent,le_date_type_loc_pro_cen_pat",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 26699730,
    "filtered": 95.92,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using filesort"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "locations",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "4",
    "ref": "e_production.ledger_entries.location_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100.00,
    "Extra": "Using where"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "providers",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "4",
    "ref": "e_production.ledger_entries.provider_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100.00,
    "Extra": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "ledger_entry_types",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "eq_ref",
    "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
    "key": "PRIMARY",
    "key_len": "4",
    "ref": "e_production.ledger_entries.ledger_entry_type_id",
    "rows": 1,
    "filtered": 100.00,
    "Extra": null
  }
]
```

This runs for a six month window in about 65 seconds. I am trying to get it under our timeout threshold for a related service of 30 seconds.

Comment: How many distinct values exists for type column? I see you have index  `index_ledger_entries_on_date_and_type` on (`date`,`type`).  Have you tried an index on type, date instead?

Comment: There are 5 distinct values for `type`. I tried adding INDEX(type, date) - the EXPLAIN changed to use `index_ledger_entries_on_location_id` as the index for `ledger_entries`, but the execution time did not change appreciably.

Answer (score 2):

- I assume `date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-30'` includes more than about 20% of ledger_entries`?
- Drop `INDEX(a)`, if you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.
- Since you have a specific test `locations.active = true`, `LEFT JOIN  locations` is actually `INNER JOIN  locations`.
- Please qualify all column names (to make it easier to interpret which tables are referenced).

None of the above will speed up the query.  Here's something that will:

Use `UNION` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT ....  (( replacing ledger_entries with le3 ))
    FROM (
        ( SELECT le.id
            FROM ledger_entries AS le
            WHERE  le.type IS NULL
              AND  le.date >= '2022-01-01'
              AND  le.date  < '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
        ) UNION ALL (
          SELECT le.id
            FROM ledger_entries AS le
            WHERE ledger_entries.type IN
                    ('Procedure', 'Adjustment', 'AncillarySale')
              AND  le.date >= '2022-01-01'
              AND  le.date  < '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
        )
         ) AS le2
    JOIN ledger_entries AS le3 ON le3.id = le2.id
    JOIN locations  ON le3.location_id = locations.id
    LEFT JOIN ... (etc)
    WHERE locations.active
    GROUP BY  le3.date, le3.provider_id, le3.location_id, 
              le3.ledger_entry_type_id;
```

and replace index_ledger_entries_on_type with

```
INDEX(type, date)
```

Even faster... If it is practical to summarize the data daily (or monthly), then build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) and do the query against it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! To answer your question, 2022-01-01 to 2022-06-30 is approx 700k rows, out of the 26M currently in the table.

Adding the INDEX(type, date) had no noticeable impact on the original query execution time, but the EXPLAIN changed from using no key on `ledger_entries` to using `index_ledger_entries_on_location_id`. 

The suggested query runs quite a bit slower - about 104 seconds.